# Efficiently creating a dictionary of dictionaries from very large csv data

Tags: python, dictionary, mapreduce

I have data for different locations split by date and time in a comma separated file. A sample for location `201682` is shown below:

```
Location    Date        Time            Data
201682      3/15/2011   1:00:00 AM      10
201682      3/16/2011   1:00:00 AM      12
201682      3/15/2011   2:00:00 AM      32
201682      3/16/2011   2:00:00 AM      31
201682      3/15/2011   3:00:00 AM      21
201682      3/16/2011   3:00:00 AM      20
201682      3/15/2011   4:00:00 AM      45
201682      3/16/2011   4:00:00 AM      56
201682      3/15/2011   5:00:00 AM      211
201682      3/16/2011   5:00:00 AM      198
201682      3/15/2011   6:00:00 AM      512
201682      3/16/2011   6:00:00 AM      324
```

The file I have runs for millions of lines of data. In order to process the data I am trying to create a dictionary object in Python. It will essentially use the location as a key and store the rest of the data in a list. This is my (futile) attempt at this:

```
import csv

headers = None
records = {}

reader=csv.reader(open(csvFile))
for row in reader:
    if reader.line_num == 1:
        headers = row[1:]
    else:
        records[row[0]] = dict(zip(headers, row[1:]))

print records['201682']
```

The output I get is shown below:

```
{'Date':'3/16/2011', 'Time':'6:00:00 AM', 'Data':'324'}
```

I wanted the data to look this way:

```
{['Date':'3/15/2011', 'Time':'1:00:00 AM', 'Data':'10'],
 ['Date':'3/16/2011', 'Time':'1:00:00 AM', 'Data':'12'],
 ['Date':'3/15/2011', 'Time':'2:00:00 AM', 'Data':'32'],
 ['Date':'3/16/2011', 'Time':'2:00:00 AM', 'Data':'31'],
 ['Date':'3/15/2011', 'Time':'3:00:00 AM', 'Data':'21'],
 ['Date':'3/16/2011', 'Time':'3:00:00 AM', 'Data':'20'],
 ['Date':'3/15/2011', 'Time':'4:00:00 AM', 'Data':'45'],
 ['Date':'3/16/2011', 'Time':'4:00:00 AM', 'Data':'56'],
 ['Date':'3/15/2011', 'Time':'5:00:00 AM', 'Data':'211'],
 ['Date':'3/16/2011', 'Time':'5:00:00 AM', 'Data':'198'],
 ['Date':'3/15/2011', 'Time':'6:00:00 AM', 'Data':'512'],
 ['Date':'3/16/2011', 'Time':'6:00:00 AM', 'Data':'324']}
```

The intention is to store the `Date`, `Time` and `Data` information for every record in a dictionary. Then to lump all the data for a particular location within a list. Finally, create a dictionary of such lists having the location as the key.

How can I get the code to do this? Also, is there a more efficient way to do this? The data file I have is close to 24GB in size. [Is there a map-reduce approach in Python for multiple threads - I am very very new to the map reduce paradigm...]. Help much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not even sure what your intended data is supposed to be.  You have a strange mixture of dictionary and list syntax in there which isn't valid python.

Comment: @mgilson: The intention is to create a data object that uses the location as a key and identifies all the records for that location. So the key will not be unique to one dictionary but to a list of dictionaries. Makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal you've describe is to end up with a data structure. However, most data structures are meant to service a *query* -- what exactly are you trying to extract from this information? Without knowing that, it's hard to say what would be most efficient or whether map-reduce is something that would be helpful.

That said, it seems like the easiest thing to do would be to build up the dictionary you've described to contain row ids rather than the row data themselves. That would certainly save some space, and still allow you to answer your queries. If, however, your data set 24GB on disk, then you'll need more than that to keep it in RAM. Supposing that given a query, getting the row IDs would be sufficient, then I suggest:

```
import csv

headers = None
records = {}

reader = csv.reader(open(csvFile))

# So we can have lists as entries by default
from collections import defaultdict
index = {}

for row in reader:
    if reader.line_num == 1:
        headers = row
        # We'll set up rows to be a dictionary with one defaultdict
        # for each of the headers, mapping the unique values to the
        # rows that match
        index = dict((header, defaultdict(list)) for header in headers)
    else:
        for header, value in zip(headers, row):
            index[header][value].append(reader.line_num)

# Now, you can find out which rows have, say, 'Location' set to a given value
index['Location']['201682']

# Or all the rows with 'Time' set to '1:00:00 AM'
index['Time']['1:00:00 AM']
```

That said, this is just using python dictionaries to build up an index, and there are tools much better suited to this. Off hand, mySQL comes to mind, especially if you're going to be doing a lot of ad-hoc queries. It likely supports better indexing than a dictionary can offer and doesn't suffer from the constraint of having to fit into memory.